# Select only one element, not all element - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3-4 checkbox (`btnA`/`btnB` etc.) and they except first checkbox all other checkbox having `hidechktext` class. I also have 3-4 images in separate `div` and except one they all have `hidechktext` class.

I want when I click the checkbox(`btnA`) it will change the checkbox to `btnB` as well as change the `img1` to `img2`. I can change the checkbox... Meaning when I click first checkbox(`btnA`), it adds the class `hidechktext` to `btnA` and removes the class `hidechktext` from `btnB` so that it can be seen.

My problem is I can not change the picture, the checkbox are replaced by next one...
But in case of image it adds `hidechktext` to all images and that's why after clicking the checkbox no image is showing.

Please help me doing that just a small problem it is.

**HTML codes**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 halftop" align="center">
  <div class="card" style="width:100%;" align="center">
    <!---Image type animation--> 
    <div class="imgall">
      <figure class="imgmain">
        <img src="img/pane/pane1.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="imgmain hidechktext">
        <img src="img/pane/pane2.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="imgmain hidechktext">
        <img src="img/pane/pane3.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!---Image type animation-->
  </div>
</div>
<!---First like button-->
<div class="col-2 mobileview halftoplike text-center">
  <div class="imgtext">      
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img1" id="chkimg1">
      <label for="chkimg1">
        <p> 
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
          BtnA
        </p> 
      </label> 
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgtext hidechktext">      
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img2" id="chkimg2">
      <label for="chkimg2">
        <p> 
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
          BtnB
        </p> 
      </label> 
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgtext hidechktext">      
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img3" id="chkimg3">
      <label for="chkimg3">
        <p> 
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i> <br/>
          BtnC
        </p> 
      </label> 
    </a>
  </div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.hidechktext{
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery code**

```
//for checkbox btn change
$('.fa-thumbs-o-up').on('click', function() {
  var LikeC = $('.imgtext').last();
  var LikeA = $('.imgtext').first();
  if (!LikeC.hasClass("hidechktext")) {
    LikeA.removeClass('hidechktext');
  }
  $(this).siblings().parents('.imgtext').next().removeClass('hidechktext');
  $(this).parents('.imgtext').addClass('hidechktext');
});

//for image change    

$('.fa-thumbs-o-up').on('click', function() {
  $('.imgall').children().siblings('.imgmain:first').removeClass('hidechktext'); 
  $('.imgmain').prepend().addClass('hidechktext');
});
```

The problem is the image is not replacing with the next image but the btn is replacing .

Comment: Please add your codes as HTML/CSS/JS snippet so that it could be tested and altered more easily by people who may want to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there are some issue on your script, I just try to change your script as below by using data attribute.

```js
//for checkbox btn change
$('.checkMe').on('click', function() {
  var LikeC = $('.imgtext').last();
  var LikeA = $('.imgtext').first();
  if (!LikeC.hasClass("hidechktext")) {
    LikeA.removeClass('hidechktext');
  }
  $(this).siblings().parents('.imgtext').next().removeClass('hidechktext');
  $(this).parents('.imgtext').addClass('hidechktext');
});

//for image change    
$('.checkMe').on('click', function() {
  var imgFigure = $(this).data('img');
  $('.imgmain').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(imgFigure)) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidechktext');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('hidechktext');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.hidechktext {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 halftop" align="center">
  <div class="card" style="width:100%;" align="center">
    <!---Image type animation-->
    <div class="imgall">
      <figure class="imgmain imgFigure1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/OXT6itR.png" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="imgmain imgFigure2 hidechktext">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/07/c6/8b/07c68b13577d92dbabd5ca096ef5868f--fractal-images-art-fractal.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure class="imgmain imgFigure3 hidechktext">
        <img src="http://picpulp.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/tumblr_m5fj2mynYy1rwswb1o1_500.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
    </div>
    <!---Image type animation-->
  </div>
</div>
<!---First like button-->
<div class="col-2 mobileview halftoplike text-center">
  <div class="imgtext">
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img1" id="chkimg1">
      <label class="checkMe" for="chkimg1" data-img="imgFigure2">
        <p>
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i>
          <br/> BtnA
        </p>
      </label>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgtext hidechktext">
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img2" id="chkimg2">
      <label class="checkMe" for="chkimg2" data-img="imgFigure3">
        <p>
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i>
          <br/> BtnB
        </p>
      </label>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="imgtext hidechktext">
    <a class="nextimgs">
      <input class="hidecheck" type="checkbox" name="imganimate" value="img3" id="chkimg3">
      <label class="checkMe" for="chkimg3" data-img="imgFigure1">
        <p>
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x"></i>
          <br/> BtnC
        </p>
      </label>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to get the value of single images? like on click next the name of the image can be stored thru jquery attr?

Comment: yes you can, through another data attr you can do that as like `data-img="imgFigur12"`